# Cache option in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, ssis-2012

I'm creating an ETL Package, and have to perform lookups against two very large fact tables. What would be the best Cache mode to select in this case and why?

Thank you

Comment: I managed to sort it out myself. I redefined my query to get only the most relevant data at a certain point in time.

Comment: write this as an answer even if you asked the question.